# How to improve my pushover process

Tags: asp.net, ftp

Currently, in order to push my website live I upload files to the server via FTP using FileZilla. If a user reloads the site when I'm pushing over the website DLL, they'll get a `File is being used by another process` type of error.

Are there any better pushover techniques I can make use of to get around this issue or any techniques that are generally better than using at FTP client to upload my site?

Answer (score 2):

You can always upload an app_offline.htm file while you are deploying the new site. If you do this in an asp.net application the user will be directed to the app_offline.html file no matter what page they try to load/reload. When you're ready for them to access the site again you simply remove/delete/rename the file (i usually just rename it so it's a simple rename to get the site back into offline mode).

http://weblogs.asp.net/dotnetstories/archive/2011/09/24/take-an-asp-net-application-offline.aspx

Comment: It looks like it still errors out if a user tries to load the site just as I'm pushing over a new DLL, even when the app_offline.html file is there.